# Is it possible to use depth first search to search every node?

Tags: java, search, tree, depth-first-search

I'm looking into depth first search and the examples I found are looking for a particular answer, lets say the number 10.

It goes through the tree discarding every node that isn't 10 and stop when it finds 10.

Is it possible to use depth first search or another algorithm to search every branch of the tree? I would like it to run a scenario and come up with a value and store that into a variable possibly named `highestValue`.

It would then search the next branch and get a value and store that into a variable possibly named Value. Then it would compare highestValue to Value and `if (Value > highestValue)` `highestValue = Value`.

It would repeat the process until it is finished running every possible scenario. Any ideas? I should mention I'm writing this in Java.

Comment: Just... don't tell it to stop when it reaches your target? I don't see what the issue is here. Can you provide the code and a specific input/output you're looking for?

Comment: @Eric I'm still working on figuring out how it's all going to work but for the most part, I was just wondering if it was even possible to do tell it not to stop since every example I found had a specific goal in mind. And you just answered my question so Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

DFS is easiest if we want to visit every node in the graph. However, if we have a very large tree and want to be prepared to quit when we get too far from the original node, DFS can search thousands of ancestors of the node but never search all of the nodes children.
Strictly speaking, it depends on how the data in your graph is organize. [Source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/098478280X)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're still wondering how it might work, this piece of code might help you figure that out. This works for graphs, take a look. It DFSes every node, but stops when it reaches the node we want to find.

To get the highest value, just store the max value into an int variable, and continue searching and comparing each node's data to the current max inside the int variable.

```
public static boolean search(Graph g, Node start, Node end) {
    LinkedList<Node> stack = new LinkedList<Node>();
    for (Node u : g.getNodes()) {
        u.state = State.Unvisited;
    }
    start.state = State.Visiting;
    stack.add(start);
    Node u;
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        u = stack.removeFirst();
        if (u != null) {
            for ( Node v : u.getAdjacent() ) {
                if (v.state == State.Unvisited) {
                    if (v == end) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        v.state = State.Visiting;
                        stack.add(v);
                    }
                }
            }
            u.state = State.Visited;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```